# Prevent scrolling when mouse is dragged to edge of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click my mouse and move it to the edge of the screen, the page automatically scrolls in that direction (at least on Chrome).

For instance, if you go to: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=anything)

Press the mouse down and move your cursor to the bottom of the screen while keeping the button pressed, the page will scroll downwards.

I would like to disable this on my own website, and prevent the browser from scrolling automatically. Can this be done?

At first I thought it had to do with text selection, and I tried

```
$("body").disableSelection()
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable text selection with CSS:

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

- Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/1737158
- Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

But it will not help to stop drag.

You can use `window.scrollTo(x, y);` to scroll user to one or other location. You can bind on scroll event [Capturing the "scroll down" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670834/capturing-the-scroll-down-event) and check mouse position [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position). So it's basically all you need to disable such behavior.

I've just tried some other funny ways
- disable mouse events with css, disable selection with css, disable mouse event bubbling with JS. Nothing helps for your situation. Try doing with those tactics wrote before.

Comment: window.scrollTo just makes things worse, because now it's trying to go up and down at the same time making the page "shake". I'm afraid this will not work..