# How to toggle class on scrollToTop and scrollToBottom in only Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

i need a way to add a class when the document scrolled to top and remove it when document scrolled to bottom with only Javascript no jquery or any other plugin.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: why tag with jquery if you don't want jquery answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing the "scroll down" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670834/capturing-the-scroll-down-event)

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757060/4450187

Comment: What have you already tried...

Comment: i did not try because i don't know a way to do that

Comment: sorry about Jquery tag i removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check if the page has been scrolled to the bottom.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
     //bottom of page
    document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].classList.add("red");
}
}
```

You can use this function to check if the page has been scrolled to the top.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;

if (D.scrollTop == 0)
    {
       //top of page
        document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].classList.remove("red");
    }    
}
```

```css
.header{
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

html, body{
 height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
         //bottom of page
        document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].classList.add("red");
    }

   var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;

if (D.scrollTop == 0)
 {
       //top of page
  document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].classList.remove("red");
 }    
   };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no man that is not what i'm asking for. i said toggle this code just add class not remove class

Comment: @rateb Could you please explain what you mean by that?