# How could I make my header background turn white on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to achieve this during my learning process. I just started with javascript but everything is very blurry for me. How could i achieve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgqaF.png)

[here is the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgqaF.png)

[here is the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXlJH.png)

Comment: It would be better to add your code as text instead of images.

Comment: Please add the code you are linking to directly to your question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing the "scroll down" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670834/capturing-the-scroll-down-event)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your header HTML add header class, where you need to change the background.

Add this jquery for adding and removing class in scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scroll <= 500) { // change this 500 by your own need
        $(".header").addClass("lightHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".header").addClass("darkHeader").removeClass("lightHeader");
    }
}
```

Add this CSS:

```
.darkHeader {
   backgound-color: #000; //whatever color you want
}
.lightHeader {
   backgound-color: #fff; //whatever color you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
$("#myheader").css("background-color", "white");
}
</script>


<header id="myheader">This is my div.</div>
```

Comment: Seems a shame to load a whole library to achieve this.

Comment: He/She can fix :) i just gave an idea