# Animate objects everytime I scroll down a web page

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-animations

I want the animation to happen everytime I scroll down (only down, not up). I have come up with a js code but it works for both scrolling up and down.

```
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame || function(callback){
  window.setTimeout(callback,1000/60)
};

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".question-box");

function loop(){
  elements.forEach(element => {
    if (isElementInViewport(element)){
      element.classList.add("visible");
    }else{
      element.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
  scroll(loop);
}

loop();

// Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  // special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}
```

Comment: Just try using Intersection observer API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757060/9140740

Comment: Please add HTML to your post so that the code can be tested

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called [scrollreveal.js](https://scrollrevealjs.org/), Here is an example of scroll reveal:

[anijs.github.io/examples/scrollreveal](https://anijs.github.io/examples/scrollreveal/)

You can read the documentation here:

[scrollrevealjs.org/guide](https://scrollrevealjs.org/guide/hello-world.html)