# How has Facebook built this fixed-on-scroll box with iOS support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, onscroll

How has Facebook built this fixed-on-scroll box (sticky sidebar) on their new prasentation site [for the new newsfeed](https://www.facebook.com/about/newsfeed)?

[image]

I know [many of the solutions](http://byjakewithlove.com/treehouse/sticky-sidebar/) for doing this but this one is special. The switching between `position: relative` and `position: fixed` works at the touchmove event (not special) but it also works on the iOS scroll pan!

I thought that wasn't possible - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863570/1159384). How did they do this?

Comment: What iOS version are you using? I'm currently trying to manage something similar in iOS 6, but I can't get it to work. Even the facebook page is not updating on scroll pan.

Comment: position: sticky; was supported with iOS 6.1 I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly it uses the webkit function `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Explanation is found [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit).

Comment: it's almost not supported at all sadly... http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky