# Get scrollTop() while scrolling on iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, web-applications

I'm trying to get the scrollTop() value while scrolling a website on the iPad/iPhone.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

I'm using this code for normal desktop browsers. On Safari with the Mac the console shows every pixel while scrolling. But on the iPad, I only get the value when the scrolling stops.

How can I get every scrollTop value while scrolling even on the iPad?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2863547/1414562

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either because it does not return the pixels while the bounce/rubberband/anything effect, that iOS scrolling provides

Comment: You have to use the gesturechange event to, it seems to give this exact behaviour. I outline it on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad/17195346#17195346

Answer (score 1):

This limitation changed in [iOS 8](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/)

This continues to log $(window).scrollTop() after touchend while the inertia/bounce effect is running:

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
console.log($(window).scrollTop());});
```

tested on iPad 9.2, iPhone 9.3.4

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
  var currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(currentPosition);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make overflow hidden or scrollTop wont work on safari.
Just make overflow: auto;

```
html,body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using `window.pageYOffset` and `window.pageXOffset`.