# scrollTop doesn't work with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I have a single page application built in Phonegap and I had been having problems with iOS device (not android) whilst using:

```
 document.querySelector('page').scrollTop = 0;
```

If i navigate to a different page and the view I just came from  had `scrollTop //38` it would keep the same `scrollTop //38` as I only changed content inside of `page`.

So I would use the above `jS` to edit the scroll top, so doing this:

```
 document.querySelector('page').scrollTop //outputs 38
```

Fantastic, however when i touch the screen it would jump down `38px`and resetting `scrollTop = 38`.

If i remove

```
 page {
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```

Then this problem would no longer occur, but also smooth scrolling would stop and would only scroll so long as your were touching the screen.

Does anybody now how I can use `scrollTop` correctly whilst keeping this sliding effect natively active?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad/17195346#17195346

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the query selector `page` in both JS and CSS.

The selector `page` means the tag(s) with tag name `page` which is something like this:

```
<page foo="bar"></page>
```

which is not a valid standard HTML5 element.

Do you means `.page` or `#page` which is class name and id respectively.

I have tried it and every things work fine.

HTML

```
<div class="page">
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
    foo<br>bar<br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('.page').scrollTop = 0;
```

The page didn't jump unexpectedly when I touch on the screen or on it.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.page').scrollTop);
```

Comment: Nope, its just `page`, that aside. I think you have misread my problem, all the same thanks for trying. However its when I jump between page loads, now that it doesn't give me back the correct scrollTop value, its that when i set it to 0, then touch the screen it will reset to its original state, in this case `38`

Comment: @GajasKuizinas - So you're saying you have an element that looks like this in your HTML? `<page> /*content here*/ </page>`