# jQuery position DIV fixed on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to fixed an element on top, when this element touch the top of the window, when the user scroll down.
On scroll down everything works (added a class with the fixed position), but when I scroll up doesn't work.
but i don't understand why :(
i created a jsfiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/8h4knr9r/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     var distance = $('#navigation-sections').offset().top;

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#navigation-sections').offset().top) {
         $('#navigation-sections').addClass("affix");

     } else {
         $('#navigation-sections').removeClass("affix");
     }
 });
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the initial distance outside the scroll function - otherwise it 
will get recalculated every scroll. Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/donal/8h4knr9r/5/

The JS should look like this:

```
var distance = $('#navigation-sections').offset().top; 

$(window).scroll(function () {

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
         $('#navigation-sections').addClass("affix");

     } else {
         $('#navigation-sections').removeClass("affix");
     }
 });
```

Comment: thanks.
i noticed that on tablet and mobile the performance is very slow.
the position fixed is changed only when the scroll is finished.
how can I get better this? is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Try the gesturechange event. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17195346/379855