# it doesn't work to move when I scroll down on iphone only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to stop menu-bar when menu-bar come to TOP on iphone. it works to stop menu-bar at top position, but when back scrolling, it doesn't work smoothly. menu-bar stay top position for a moment.(Android works to move both)
What should I do?

thank you.

this is CSS

```
.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width:100%;
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    }
```

this is JS

```
$(function() {
        var nav = $('.menu-bar');
        var offsetTop = nav.offset().top;
        var floatMenu = function() {
            var $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if ($scrollTop >= offsetTop) {
                    nav.addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass('fixed');
                }
        }
        $(window).scroll(floatMenu);
        $('body').bind('touchmove', floatMenu);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB7t4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEVvi.png)

Comment: Good reading on that behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2863570/1414562

Comment: Thank you for replay me, I try to read it.