# Add class during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm trying to add a class to a div on scroll, but on iOS, the class is only added once the scroll is completed. How can I add the class during the scroll?

```
$(window).on('scroll.nav', () => {
      $(window).scrollTop() >= 110 ? $('body').addClass('menu-fixed') : $('body').removeClass('menu-fixed');  
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad

Comment: epascarello - this question concerns the scroll event, and if you actually read it, it is out of date since iOS 8 was released. The question is asking about dom manipulation on scroll.

Comment: And that said that the onscroll is only fired when the scroll event is complete.

Comment: epascarello - that is not true. It fires all throughout a scroll.