# Displaying no background-color until release finger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website. Website has navigation, that it transparent (`background: transparent`), when you open it. when you start scrolling, it becomes colorful, some color like grey, midnight blue, or something. And there is a div, at the bottom of the page. when you scroll enough, as bottom, as possible, the navigation become `display:none` and if you scroll bit top again, it will have `display:block` again. That JUST works, but there is a problem on iPad (well, does not tested on other touchscreens, but probably same).

Problem is, that, when i scroll to the bottom of the page, header disappears, but when i than want to scroll top again, navigation will appear, but with no `background-color`..until i release my finger. Weird, right?

Hope, you understand, there are photos:

[image: When scrolling top, it should have background-color, but when holding, has transparent background as shown]

When scrolling top, it should have `background-color`, but when holding, has transparent background as shown

[image: When you scroll to the bottom of the page, menu disappears, this is great...]

When you scroll to the bottom of the page, menu disappears, this is great.

[image: this should happen, when you scroll up enough, but it does not work, if you are still scrolling -> holding the screen.]

This should happen, when you scroll up enough, but it does not work, if you are still scrolling -> holding the screen

Now, There is JSFiddle... CSS got over 1500 lines, important is

```
#main-header {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    top:0;
    background-color:#34495e;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL1dpas/       <- JS fiddle **NOTE** It is so messy, no images, just cause of code, and JS!

And important link to working website

http://david.addagio.cz/gospel

And **NOTE** 2

```
$(function(){
  $(window).on('load scroll resize orientationchange', function () {
      var my_height = $("#full_contact").height();
      var important = $(document).height();
      var final = important - my_height;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < final) { 
        $('#main-header').css("display", "block");
        $('#main-header').css("background-color", "#34495e");
        document.getElementById("#navigace");
        $('#navigace').addClass('.navigace_scroll');
        $('.navigace_scroll').removeClass('#navigace');

    }
    else{
        $('#main-header').css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

This is the primary code, used for this whole when-bottom-menu-disappear animation

My question again is... in minimal:

"Why it works, and it has the `display:block;`, but until I release finger, it has NO background-color???"

Well, hope, it will help solve my problem, PLEASE help, in hurry with this.

Any help -> I'll be glad

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be able to use javascript's 'onmouseup', the equivalent of which for touchscreen devices is 'ontouchend'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad). I had the similar issue with scrollToTop button. I've just remembered, that iOS have some strange behavior w/ firing scroll event and also with js executing in time of scrolling (maybe not your case).
Maybe it helps you to understand the issue.

Comment: WOW! exactly! well, this is my problem, i will try, if it will solve it, you got 50 rep points :-) ;-)