# scrollTop equivalent on Ipad

Tags: jquery

I'm using a function to detect `scrollTop` and the do something. Its working on desktop browser but not on mobile devices:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 80) {
      $('h2.main-info').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
      $('h2.main-info').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

What would be the equivalent of `scrollTop` function for iPad?

Comment: That should work just fine on mobile devices as well. I've tested to most smartphones but iPad though. What do you mean by its not working?

Comment: @choz by not working I mean that after 80px of scroll on an iPad the class `scrolled` is not applied to `h2.main-info`.

Comment: Can you try with `alert` and see if it's firing after `80px`? Or maybe try `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `$(this).scrollTop()`, but I doubt it'd make any difference..

Comment: I've just tried it, the `alert` doesn't show. I'm testing it on Xcode, don't think that makes any difference :/

Comment: I dont have macs, I usually test on apple devices by using alerts :). Maybe this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad) helps.  You should also try whether that `scroll` event of yours is even firing at all..