# Improve parallax scrolling on tablets and mobile

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile, parallax

I have an issue regarding a parallax scrolling effect I have on the hero cover on a website that I'm working on.

So I want to make the background image on the hero cover scroll at a slower rate than the website as a whole.

Do achieve this I use the following method:

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
  || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
  || function(f){setTimeout(f, 1000/60)}

var hero = document.getElementsByClassName('hero');

function parallax(){
  var scrolltop = window.pageYOffset;
  hero[0].style.backgroundPosition = '25% ' + (+scrolltop * .5 - 217) + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

  requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
  
}, false)
```

```css
.hero{

 padding: 140px 0px;

 background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/0e/18/3b/0e183b91a011639bfed7ebfd6a1f7063.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 25% -217px;
 background-size: cover; 
}

.paddingTop{
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.paddingBottom{
  padding: 800px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='paddingTop'>
</div>

<div class="hero">
</div>

<div class='paddingBottom'>
</div>
```

On desktop it's fine, but the trouble starts with tablet and mobile devices. The result on such devices can turn up very choppy and/or the animation entirely lags behind when scrolling the website.

This problem doesn't appear to be consistent with all mobile browsers though.

Here is a little report:

- Internet on Mobile Android - choppy
- Firefox on Mobile Android - very choppy
- Chrome on Mobile Android - perfectly smooth, no issues
- Firefox on an Android Tablet - the choppiness is less severe than the
  mobile counterpart
- Chrome on an Android Tablet - choppy
- Samsung Internet on an Android Tablet - extremely choppy
- Safari on iOS - perfectly smooth

Answer (score 3):

Parallax scrolling is notoriously tricky in mobile.

Historically, javascript solutions have had issues in mobile because the `onscroll` event was [fired when the page *stops* scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863570/772086).

You could try this promising CSS-driven solution described in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/performant-parallaxing:

> The CSS for this approach looks like so:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin: 0 0;
}

.parallax-child {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
```

> Which assumes a snippet of HTML like this:

```
<div class="container”>
  <div class="parallax-child”></div>
</div>
```

However, as noted in the link, this technique currently has pitfalls too - particularly in Mobile Safari.