# angular 6 - @Inject(DOCUMENT) build scrollTop not work in iphone chrome, safari

Tags: angular

I using `@Inject(DOCUMENT)` to build `scrollTop` can be work on PC chrome, but not work in iphone.

for exapmle:

structure:

`<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>`

`app-header` component:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

@HostListener('window:scroll', [])onWindowScroll() {
    console.log(this.document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  }
```

Sliding up and down, the `this.document.documentElement.scrollTop` value always 0 in iphone 6S. but work in PC chrome browser.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad is this what you're running into, possibly?

Comment: Thank you, maybe this is the problem,the strange thing, I try to that `$(window).scrollTop()` is working, but it has not been recommended to use jquery in angular?

Comment: Yeah... that's typically not recommended, that's true. I might be incorrect, but do you need to even do the DOCUMENT injection stuff still? I thought you could access `window.onscroll`  event straight from an angular component now. And subsequently, maybe you can call `window.scrollTo(0,0)` to scroll to the top. None of that requiring jQuery.

Comment: ok, thank. I hope that after the angular will improve this part, compared to jquery, angular scroll related functions are not convenient to use.

Comment: jQuery methods are just wrappers around things that already exist in some way in javascript. Did the two items I mentioned above, the `window.onscroll` event hook and the `window.scrollTo(0,0)` work for you in your angular component? If you put something like `window.onscroll = (event) => { console.log('scrolling', event) }` in your `ngOnInit` I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: Yeah, `window.scrollTo(0,0)` is work in my component, Is it a good way to use `window` directly? `window.onscroll` can be using  '@HostListener', it's work. I mean like `$('#element').scrollTop()`, `$('#element').position().top` event, I don't know how to achieve these events in angular.

Comment: using `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` run with angular universal, the log show the error message `window is not defined`

Comment: I am not seeing that... what version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular 6 (6.0.3), `window.scrollTo(0,0)` is work, but when the angular universal(node.js server) starts, there will be an error message `ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that you use angular universal. I googled that error and there are quite a few things that come up. You may want to look at them.