# Load more item when scroll don't work in mobile/laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with loading other items (with mysqli / ajax), works perfectly on the desktop PC but does not work on the mobile and laptop..

(Sorry for my English)

Script in index

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var min = 5;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "get_more.php",
        data: {
          username: document.getElementById("user").value,
          min: min
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          min += 3;
          $("#postList").append(data);

          if (data == "") {
            $("#load_data_message").html(
              "<p class='text-center'>No More Data Found | End of List</p>"
            );
            action = "active";
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance, if you need anything else let me know

***EDIT 1:***
I tried this but it doesn't work the same:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", ScrollStart, false); 
document.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll, false); function ScrollStart() { 
} 
function Scroll() { 
if((window.pageYOffset == $(document).height() - $(window).height())) { 
alert("test"); 

} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the issue lies with `scroll` event behaving differently on mobile, plus you should rely on pageYOffset and not `scrollTop`. Look here:

[javascript scroll event for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad)

Comment: I tried as you told me, is it possible to make the call when it has reached the maximum scroll value?

Comment: It should be possible, how does your height comparison looks now?