# How to determine when scrolling reaches the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have an infinite scroll with this system. However, it doesn't work on a mobile browser.

How can I get it to work on mobile?

```js
function appendNewLine(){
  $("#article").append("maindiv new add<br>");
  
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var doch = $(document).innerHeight(); 
        var winh = $(window).innerHeight(); 
        var bottom = doch - winh; 
        if (bottom <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            console.log("Bottom at");
            appendNewLine();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article">
main line1<br>
main line2<br>
main line3<br>
main line4<br>
main line5<br>
main line6<br>
main line7<br>
main line8<br>
main line9<br>
main line10<br>
main line11<br>
main line12<br>
main line13<br>
main line13<br>
main line14<br>
main line15<br>
main line16<br>
main line17<br>
main line18<br>
main line19<br>
main line20<br>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in snippet?

Comment: you should check [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) also.

Comment: I added Snipet . it works on Desktop but not mobile

Comment: I will check the code and let you know.

Comment: I found the soluytion here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad `$(window).scroll(function() { ` works instead of `$(window).on('scroll', function () {`