# How to scroll the canvas on touch device? (three.js)

Tags: animation, three.js

I’ve a question that I searched about it and nothing found.

could you please explain how to I can scroll the canvas on mobile phones?
I mean that I’m making a website and one of my section has canvas tag that i made an animation with three.js but scrolling in canvas isn’t working on touch screen.

here is the code below about my animation .

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
var cameraPosition = camera;

cameraPosition.position.set(100,0, 120);



var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    canvas: document.getElementById("viewport")
});
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
var canvas = renderer.domElement
render();

function render() {
    if (resize(renderer)) {
        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
}
camera.lookAt(100,0,-120);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
})

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
// to disable zoom
controls.enableZoom = false;

// to disable rotation
controls.enableRotate = false;

// to disable pan
controls.enablePan = false;


var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffbb );
spotLight.position.set( 10, 10, 150 );
scene.add( spotLight );


var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load( './iphonex/out.glb', function ( gltf ) {

    var object = gltf.scene;
    object.position.set(0,0, 0);


    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    animation();

    function animation() {

        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            animation();
        })
    }
    function updateCamera() {
        object.rotation.y = 0.1 + window.scrollX * Math.PI / 360;

    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", updateCamera);

    // controls.noRotate = true;
    // controls.noZoom = true;
    // window.addEventListener('scroll', onscroll
    // , false);
    // window.addEventListener('wheel', onscroll, false);    var animate = function () {
    //     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //     renderer.render(scene, camera);
    // }

}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );
```

Comment: Why are you using `OrbitControls` if you disable zooming, panning and orbiting? Consider to remove `OrbitControls`, use `camera.lookAt()` to orient your camera and try it again.

Comment: @Mugen87 I've disabled the orbit controls to stick the object with the scroll bar orienting. I need to when user scrolling the windows then animation play not automatically.this is why when user scrolling the window the camera can change the view to my object.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event works differently than you would expect on mobile.
[javascript scroll event for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad)

Comment: Well I know that is difference between iPhone and iPad scroll event thanks for reply me back,but the problem is I want to set canvas scroll bar to my main window scroll bar.

Comment: hmm.. So you want to capture the scroll event in the canvas and then pass it through to the window, so when you scroll on the canvas the whole page scrolls? Am i getting this right?

Comment: absolutely I want to scroll the canvas through the window scroll.

Comment: That's the opposite of what i just said. What happens if you, inside the scroll event, do document.body.scrollTop += event.deltaY, or something?

Comment: Yup, I did that but nothing response from the canvas...and still it's static and won't work.

Comment: Ah, it's supposed to be document.documentElement.scrollTop. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp, See the third example

Comment: It won't work at all , canvas scroller is working on desktop size but in mobile version one it behave like a static element and the scroller won't scroll at all.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help with this. I can't image how this doesn't work and without an example or iphone im stuck myself too.

Comment: Well i found a way for it.My overflow was hidden because of some reason and I knew it,but I didn't have a way to delete the overflow hidden.I used the scroll magic library to  scroll the canvas behind the scene and with the window scroller now I can scroll it easily ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent upper div to prevent canvas from getting touched.

```
<div class="relative h-screen">
  <div class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen z-40"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```