# How to trigger wheel event on mobile

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a new feature on my site, namely moving between form pages using the mouse wheel.  I tried to use event "wheel" which perfectly works on desktop, however does not trigger on mobile (iphone - Safari and Chrome). I assume the mobile APIs of these browsers just do not support it, so I'm curious how to trigger it somehow.

I've tried wheel event and mousewheel as well - neither works. I'm listening along with "wheel" the event "scroll" to prevent change form pages if scroll does not reach top or bottom of the page. As I said desktop - perfect, mobile (iphone) - does not work at all.

Comment: Why don't you use just `scroll` event?

Comment: probably, this can help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad

Comment: Do you think it's normal to hook up a mouse to a mobile phone? Maybe there's a reason why mousewheel events doesn't work on mobile. Just sayin'.

Comment: I need exactly wheel event because it triggers even if there is no scroll at all on the page which possible in my case, while scroll event can't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile you should listen to [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), either `touchend` (if you want to move pages once the "scroll" motion is done) or `touchmove` (if you want to move pages during the scroll).  Either way, in your event callback you can calculate if you're at the bottom of the page and then react accordingly:

```js
if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
  // at bottom of page
}
```